# symmetric key issue in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Can any one tell me the role of symmetric key in SSIS ?

SQl Server version is 2012.

We are deploying the package and we are facing the issue  "Cannot find the symmetric key XXXX because it does not exist or you do not have permission".

I have searched on internet and find two tables which plays important role i.e. sys.symmetric_keys and sys.certificates.

Key XXXX is missing in that table sys.symmetric_keys table I don't know why it is not able to create that key in table.I am checking in SSISDB.

I have found similar keys which was created in 2014.

After Searching long I have found one link - http://www.sqlideas.com/2015/05/cannot-find-symmetric-key-x-because-it.html

Is it possible to see who has permission to the symmetric keys and certificate in SQL Server?

Please suggest what I need to do to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure of the SSIS connection, but you can view permissions on anything in SQL Server through the sys.database_permissions view. The class column says what kind of thing it is (e.g. certificate, symmetric key) , the major_id is the identifier for that type of objects (e.e. certificate_id, symmetric_key_id), and the grantee_principal_id is the user_id of the grantee. You should be able to tie it all together with that.

Answer (score 0):

As quick answer I would recommend this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331(v=sql.110).aspx

Appliance of symmetric keys varies from encryption of single column to complete database.
In case of column:
 - value returns encrypted via standard sql
 - value returns plain via sql which uses DecryptByKey function

In case of database - just imagine someone suddenly obtained backup of encrypted database and until required key is not installed (created) attempts to restore / access database contents will be unsuccessful.